# extract all reports from a specific folder

Tags: ant, migration-tool, reports-api

I am trying to migrate reports using ANT migration tool.

Basically there are hundreds of folders and thousands of reports.

i know that the wildcard * doesnot work with reports in package.xml.But its very time consuming to get the apiname of the report and then mention it in xml.\

Is there any way i can extract all the report's api name of a specific folder?

or any other idea to make this task easier?

Thanks in advance
Samir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way .I can run a SOQL to find all the reports with their api names from the specific folder

```
SELECT DeveloperName FROM Report WHERE FolderName = 'FolderName'
```

Comment: How do you get this into the `package.xml` file? Or is it a manual process to copy/paste it?